# Bootstrap Twitter Close Modal Redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an URL:

```
'/toto/errorSubmitForm/'
```

I have a modal with close button who redirect in an other URL when I click on the close button with this code

```
function clickCloseModal() {
   $('#closeModal').click(function(evt){
     evt.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = "/toto/";
   });
}
```

But when I click outside of the modal, the I leave the modal, then I search to redirect it too. I try to do this when I change the ID like that but didnt work.

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

window.onclick = function(event) {
   if (event.target == modal) {
      window.location.href = "/toto/";
   }
}
```

I give you the start of my modal

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the event on closing modal so that you can redirect to the specified url:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  window.location.href = "/toto/";
})
```